# C# .net. Having trouble catching a file as read-only when I have it open

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that is opening a .txt file for reading only. I have it working well but now I am trying to ensure that I don't access the file if someone else has it open. I have tried other solutions but I'm still having issues.

```
public string Load()
    {
        string source = MessagesAndNotifications.SourceDrawingNotSet;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "afile (*.txt)|*.txt";
        Nullable<bool> result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(openFileDialog.FileName);
        if (fileInfo.IsReadOnly == false)
        {
          if (result == true)
           {
             try
             {
              using (var fileStream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, 
              FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
              {
               using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream.Name))
               {
                //rest of the code goes on...
               }
```

The problem is my check on IsReadOnly is returning false even though I have opened the file myself. Then when my program gets to the try statement it catches the file being open and the program throws an exception and crashes.

I had originally tried having the `File.OpenRead()` method instead of `File.Open()` with parameters and got the same result.

Comment: Also `gets to the try statement it catches the file being open and the program throws an exception and crashes` are you `catch`ing this exception?

Comment: No amount of "pre-checking" can prevent the state of the file changing between performing those checks and actually attempting to open the file - so just go ahead, open the file, and be prepared to handle the exception if/when it's thrown.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ thanks I will check that out. I am catching the exception down lower in the code. Damien, I will take that advice thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The "IsReadonly"-Attribute on the FileSystem has nothing to do with the opening-Mode.

If a file is readonly, you can only read it.
But if a file is not readonly, you still can open it for reading, and read it only.

Comment: Thanks I think in this case my original code of using `File.OpenRead()` is the right solution then.

Answer (score 1):

FileInfo.IsReadOnly only checks if the file attribute "read-only" is true, not if the file is *in use*. At least, to the best of my understanding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly?view=netframework-4.8

The only way I could see that approach working is if the "read-only" flag is added to the file whenever somebody opens it.

I would instead suggest researching "in use" solutions:

[Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

Comment: Thanks I will look into that, and yeah that does make sense.